# Installing UCC SSL on ISS server for multiple domain hosted on multiple ip on Amazon EC2

Tags: iis, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have searched everywhere but have not got my problem solved. If anyone have some solution to offer please offer.

Here is my problem:

I have UCC SSL certificate which I have bought from GoDaddy (which supposedly can be used on 5 different domains). I have generated CSR from server www.example.com and in Subject Alternative Name (SAN) I have mentioned api.example.com, test.example.com, testapi.example.com. I got certificate which reflects all other sites names in SAN.

my www.example.com is on let's say ip 1

api.example.com is on ip 2

and test.example.com, testapi.example.com are both on ip 3

all sites are on windows server with IIS 7 on Amazon EC2

I have installed the certificate on main site (www.example.com) server on ip 1 and it is working fine, but how can I make it work for other sites.